# Complicated LINQ query with multiple joins syntax error

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, join

I have a query that joins two lists and creates a list of a new object and I want to enhance this with a new join and so far everything i've tried didn't seem to work.

The lists are:

```
IList<Content> result
IList<Content> resultDefault
```

The query is:

```
IEnumerable<ContentItem> joined = from x in resultDefault
join y in result on new { x.ResourceKey, x.ResourceType, x.Application } equals new { y.ResourceKey, y.ResourceType, y.Application } into g
from o in g.DefaultIfEmpty(new Content()
{
  Id = 0,
  CultureCode = cultureCode,
  ResourceKey = x.ResourceKey,
  ResourceType = x.ResourceType,
  ResourceValue = String.Empty
})

where
 (
     resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.All ||
     (resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.Translated && o.ResourceValue != String.Empty) ||
     (resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.NotTranslated && o.ResourceValue == String.Empty)
  )
  &&
  (
     string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ||
     (
         x.ResourceKey.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString) ||
         x.ResourceValue.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString) ||
         o.ResourceValue.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString)
     )
  )
select new ContentItem(o, x);
```

This so far works well.

Now, I want to add a third list

```
IList<DifferentContent> resultCollection;
```

And what I have extended ContentItem to take a third parameter of DifferentContent

So I want something like:

```
IEnumerable<ContentItem> joined = from x in resultDefault
    join y in result on new { x.ResourceKey, x.ResourceType, x.Application } equals new { y.ResourceKey, y.ResourceType, y.Application } into g
    from o in g.DefaultIfEmpty(new Content()
    {
      Id = 0,
      CultureCode = cultureCode,
      ResourceKey = x.ResourceKey,
      ResourceType = x.ResourceType,
      ResourceValue = String.Empty
    })
    join z in resultCollection on new { x.ResourceKey, x.ResourceType, x.Application, x.CultureCode } equals new { z.ResourceKey, z.ResourceType, z.Application, defaultCultureCode } into m
    from s in m.DefaultIfEmpty(new DifferentContent()
      {
          Id = 0,
          CultureCode = defaultCultureCode,
          ResourceKey = x.ResourceKey,
          ResourceType = x.ResourceType,
          ResourceValue = string.Empty
      })
    where
     (
         resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.All ||
         (resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.Translated && o.ResourceValue != String.Empty) ||
         (resourcesJoin == ResourcesJoin.NotTranslated && o.ResourceValue == String.Empty)
      )
      &&
      (
         string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ||
         (
             x.ResourceKey.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString) ||
             x.ResourceValue.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString) ||
             o.ResourceValue.ContainsIgnoreCase(searchString)
         )
      )
    select new ContentItem(o, x, s);
```

But this is invalid. The error is:

```
 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.
```

Resharper gives a "The type arguments for method ... cannot be infered". I cannot copy paste that unfortunately.

What would be the correct join syntax?

Comment: when you create a group, you loose the previous reference. At that point, you don't have `x` anymore, it's all about `g` and `z`

Comment: right, so my query is impossible?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Take a look at the examples here, please: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b. You can create a custom object when grouping.